# Could somebody explain to me how this custom View code works?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, view, drawing

```
class DrawingView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    private lateinit var mDrawPath: FingerPath
    private lateinit var mCanvasBitmap: Bitmap
    private lateinit var mCanvasPaint: Paint
    private lateinit var mDrawPaint: Paint
    private var mBrushSize = 0
    private var color = Color.BLACK
    private lateinit var canvas: Canvas

    init {
        setUpDrawing()
    }

    private fun setUpDrawing() {
        mDrawPaint = Paint()
        mDrawPath = FingerPath(color, mBrushSize.toFloat())
        mDrawPaint.color = color
        mDrawPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mDrawPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        mDrawPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mCanvasPaint = Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        mBrushSize = 20

    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        canvas = Canvas(mCanvasBitmap)

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap, 0f, 0f, mDrawPaint)
        if (!mDrawPath.isEmpty) {
            mDrawPaint.strokeWidth = mDrawPath.brushThickness
            mDrawPaint.color = mDrawPath.color
            canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath, mDrawPaint)
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val touchX = event?.x
        val touchY = event?.y

        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mDrawPath.color = color
                mDrawPath.brushThickness = mBrushSize.toFloat()

                mDrawPath.reset()
                mDrawPath.moveTo(touchX!!, touchY!!)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                mDrawPath.lineTo(touchX!!, touchY!!)

            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                mDrawPath = FingerPath(color, mBrushSize.toFloat())
            }
            else -> return false
        }

        invalidate()
        return true
    }

    internal inner class FingerPath(var color: Int, var brushThickness: Float) : Path()
}
```

So, I'm taking a course about Android Development and the instructor is building a drawing app -- and I can't understand how to code works, because he's not explaining the 'why'; so, he types a lot of code without explaining why he uses that variable or why is he overring those functions; therefore, I don't understand how to code work. Could you help me in understanding how this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DrawingView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    private lateinit var mDrawPath: FingerPath
    private lateinit var mCanvasBitmap: Bitmap
    private lateinit var mCanvasPaint: Paint
    private lateinit var mDrawPaint: Paint
    private var mBrushSize = 0
    private var color = Color.BLACK
    private lateinit var canvas: Canvas

    init {
// init block will called first when instance will be created so we
// are calling method setUpDrawing() as it is initialising everything
// that required to draw like color , brush size , brush behaviour
// (round , stroke etc .. ) . in simple manner , we can say painter is
// collecting all required tools before starting to paint

        setUpDrawing() 
    }

    private fun setUpDrawing() {
        mDrawPaint = Paint()
        mDrawPath = FingerPath(color, mBrushSize.toFloat())
        mDrawPaint.color = color
        mDrawPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mDrawPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        mDrawPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mCanvasPaint = Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        mBrushSize = 20

    }

 // this method is going to be called by system when size is going to be
// changed so we are here creating blank board on which we are going to
// draw
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        canvas = Canvas(mCanvasBitmap)

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap, 0f, 0f, mDrawPaint)
        if (!mDrawPath.isEmpty) {
            mDrawPaint.strokeWidth = mDrawPath.brushThickness
            mDrawPaint.color = mDrawPath.color
            canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath, mDrawPaint) // drawing path on canvas
        }
    }

// this method will be called by system when user is going to touch screen
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val touchX = event?.x
        val touchY = event?.y

        when (event?.action) {
// this event will be fired when user put finger on screen
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> { 
                mDrawPath.color = color
                mDrawPath.brushThickness = mBrushSize.toFloat()

                mDrawPath.reset() // reseting path before we set inital point
                mDrawPath.moveTo(touchX!!, touchY!!)// set point from where drawing will be started 
            }

// this event will be fired when user start to move it's fingure . this will be fired continually until user pickup fingure 
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                mDrawPath.lineTo(touchX!!, touchY!!)

            }
// this event will be fired when user will pick up fingure from screen
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                mDrawPath = FingerPath(color, mBrushSize.toFloat())
            }
            else -> return false
        }

        invalidate() / /refreshing layout to reflect drawing changes
        return true
    }

    internal inner class FingerPath(var color: Int, var brushThickness: Float) : Path()
}
```

Comment: Glad to know i could help you .. Happy learning

Comment: Could you -please - tell me more about the variables? Why we have two of type Paint; what's the difference between them?

Comment: i could if more code was there .. as ```mCanvasPaint``` is just initialised

Comment: What about mDrawPaint why we have mDrawPaint and mCanvasPaint?

Comment: in simple manner , ```mDrawPaint``` is painter's brush which is used to draw on canvas and it is obvious to draw something on canvas , you need brush or tool .. right ?

Comment: Yes - what about mCanavasPaint and mCanvasBitmap; what are they?

Comment: As mentioned earlier ```mCanavasPaint``` is just initialised not used anywhere in your code so add more code to know it's intention and about ```mCanvasBitmap``` it is provided to Canvas on which we are going to draw

Comment: Okay - thank you! Here is the full code: https://github.com/tutorialseu/KidsDrawingApp/blob/adding_the_color_selection/app/src/main/java/eu/tutorials/kidsdrawingapp/DrawingView.kt

Answer (score 1):

This code is a custom view class in Android for drawing. The class extends the **View class** and implements **touch event handling** to allow a user to draw on the screen.

The class defines instance variables to store the **paint**, **path**, **bitmap** and **canvas** used for drawing. It also has variables for **brush size** and **color**.

In the `setUpDrawing` method, the **paint** object for drawing and the **path** object for tracking the user's touch are set up.
In `onSizeChanged`, the **bitmap** object is created and its **canvas** object is initialized.
In `onDraw`, the **canvas** is drawn on the screen and the **path** is drawn on the canvas if it's not empty.

The `onTouchEvent` method handles touch events ***(DOWN, MOVE, UP)*** and updates the **path** accordingly.
The `FingerPath` inner class extends the `Path` class and contains the **color** and **brush size** of the **path**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through this section of the docs? [Custom View Components](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-components)

It explains the basics of creating a custom view, which on a basic level means overriding `onDraw` (where you draw the contents of the view) and maybe `onSizeChanged` (where you're told how big the view is - maybe you want to set the thickness of your paint brushes, work out where the centre of the view is etc).

`onTouchEvent` is a little more advanced, that allows you to handle the user poking at your view - the link up there gets into it, but you'll have a better understanding if you read the section on [touch gestures](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures). Broadly, you can get info about interaction events through `onTouchEvent` and work out things like whether the user touched the view, moved a finger, lifted it or moved it out of bounds etc. You'd use this info to, say, draw stuff under the user's finger for a painting app.

---

A `Canvas` is a drawing interface for a `Bitmap`. Instead of having to work out what pixels to change to what colour to draw a line or whatever, you do all your drawing through a `Canvas` that wraps that `Bitmap`. This lets you abstract the process and do high-level stuff like "draw a line", "draw an arc", "draw this entire path", "render this text" and so on. The `Canvas` works out how to make that happen in the `Bitmap`'s pixel array.

The drawing happens with `Paint`s, which you can think of as an object that says *how* the drawing happens. What does drawing a line look like? The `Paint` you use defines things like stroke width, transparency, colour etc - it's like the tool options in a paint program. It also allows you to set things like text size (if you're using it to render text) and do fancy things with blending over the pixels it's being drawn on, create shaders etc. It can also do things like control tiling if you're using a bitmap as the source image.

Generally you'll want to create these `Paint`s at startup and reuse them during your `View`'s lifespan, so it's typical to have a few of them - the one for painting the background, the one for drawing curves, the one for rendering text etc.

---

Usually in `onDraw` you just draw the view in its current state. The method takes a `Canvas` parameter - that's how you draw to the actual bitmap rendered on the UI. So if you had a knob, you could draw the circle, draw the position indicator at the appropriate location, add any text, and you're done!

For a drawing app it's a little more complicated - that "state" you need to remember and draw is the sum of all the drawing operations that have happened. You can get fancy with this (to create levels of undo) but the simplest approach is to create your *own* `Bitmap` to store the current drawing. You wrap that in its own `Canvas` (so you can draw on it) and then all the user interaction draws stuff to that `Canvas`, so you're painting on the bitmap. Then, in `onDraw`, you basically just need to paint the contents of that bitmap onto the system-provided `Canvas` so it gets drawn on-screen - just showing what you have, basically.

---

The code you have here is a little weird - you have that internal bitmap (called `mCanvasBitmap`) wrapped in a `Canvas` (called `canvas`) but you never actually draw to it. I feel like this line is meant to be rendering the `Path` you build up with the touch gestures:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    ...
    if (!mDrawPath.isEmpty) {
        ...
        canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath, mDrawPaint) // drawing path on canvas
    }
}
```

but in `onDraw`'s scope `canvas` is referring to that parameter being passed in, i.e. the `Canvas` for drawing to the screen, **not** the one wrapping `mCanvasBitmap`. So that internal bitmap always stays empty, and then you just draw the most recent path (this is a good example of watching how you name things - why not `mCanvas` to be consistent?). It never *"builds up"* an image by drawing paths onto your internal bitmap. I can't tell what the exact intent is from the code though, I just thought I'd point it out!

Comment: Thank very much for answering and providing so much detalis!